# Add Shopping cart block to cms page

Tags: php, magento

I would like to add a shopping cart block a cms page, but whenever I try, nothing happens...not even an error.

I've tried following this tutorial, http://www.magento.cc/how-to-use-php-on-a-cms-page.html.

So I created the new folders in app/code/local and then a Test.php file, yet when I try to include

```
 {{block type="YourModule_Custom/test" my_param1="value 1" another_param="value 2"}}
```

in the cms page, nothing appears.

Here's my code in the Test.php page:

```
<?php
class YourModule_Custom_Block_Test extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
{
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        echo 'TEST';
        $this->getChildHtml('header');
        return $html;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a local.xml update.  And place your content as .phtml file

```
<cms_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="Your_custom/Block" name="home_main" as="home_main" template="cms/default/home.phtml">
        </block>
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

Create a file named home.phtml in cms/default/   Then you can use your own block type to use your custom module / functions

Then add your home page content in there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are you trying to achieve. But from your question, I have a strong feeling that, you are trying to set a template of your own through CMS page. If that is the case, let us analyze why your block didn't show any output.

Your block definition is like this

```
{{block type="YourModule_Custom/test" my_param1="value 1" another_param="value 2"}}
```

There is no problem with this defintion. But it is good, if you add `name` to your block. If you set a `template` along with that, then you don't need any backend code for setting a template for your block. That is your block should look like this

```
{{block type="YourModule_Custom/test" name="test.block" template="test.phtml"}}
```

Now when magento encounter this, it will find your block, set described name to that block (for later reference this `name` will be used. However it is not relevant in this case), set template specified to your block and then render the content in that template.

So you should have a block of type that you specified. You had it right now(you dont need that `_toHtml()` inside that). Along with that you need a template file `test.phtml` and it should be in the location `app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme>/template/test.phtml`. You dont have that file right now. So create it and add this content inside that file

```
<p><?php echo "I am here. Can you see me ?"; ?></p>
```

Now check your CMS page output. You can see that content. Isn't it ?

So right now what you are  trying to do is, instead of setting a template along with that block definition, you are trying to set it through your block. Is it wrong ? Obviously, NO. There are some cases, where we need to go with that way. I assume you really need it. So again let us redifine our block in this form.

```
 {{block type="YourModule_Custom/test" name="test.block"}}
```

Hmm. Here we didn't set a template to this block right now. You can hence set it through your block definition. You used `_toHtml()` method.

```
<?php
class YourModule_Custom_Block_Test extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
{
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        echo 'TEST';
        $this->getChildHtml('header');
        return $html;
    }
}
?>
```

This method is using to set a template and then renders the content. So you are in the right track. But the problem here is, you are not setting any template!! plus your method returns a variable `$html` which holds nothing. So what should we return through a `_toHtml()` ? The answer lies in `Mage_Core_Block_Template`. Let us look on `_toHtml()` definition

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
    if (!$this->getTemplate()) {
        return '';
    }
    $html = $this->renderView();
    return $html;
}
```

Basically what this does is, it checks whether a template is set , if not return nothing. If it does renders it. That means, it is obvious that we need to set a template. So your block should look like this.

```
<?php
class YourModule_Custom_Block_Test extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    protected function _toHtml()
   {
       $this->setTemplate('test.phtml');
       $html = parent::_toHtml();
       return $html;
   }
}
```

Note that your block extends from `Mage_Core_Block_Template` rather from `Mage_Core_Bock_Abstract`. This is because `setTemplate()` method is defined in `Mage_Core_Block_Template` class. In `_toHtml()`, we are setting our template and then leave rest to our parent block. Now check whether content in `test.phtml` is showing in your CMS page. It does right ?

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer, I really appreciate this. I'm going to try it now.

Comment: This solution does not work. I created the phtml file in the directory you desicribed and I've added the new {{block}} code to the CMS page, but the "I am here" text does not show on the CMS page. Please help! Thanks again!

Comment: it should work. Because I have tested this code before I answer here. Can you show me your config file ?

Comment: Hi, the I am here text shows, but the php code like <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a> does not work. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exact what do you want. but by your question my understanding is you want to display shopping cart block into any CMS page like Home page, About us page etc.

If my understanding is right then here is one solution for you.

You can insert this code into your cms page from admin.

Admin -> CMS -> Pages -> Select any page on which you want to display block -> Click on design tab from left navigation ->Under Page Layout section insert the below code in "Layout Update XML" field. Click on save.

```
<reference name="content">
        <block type="checkout/cart" name="checkout.cart">
            <action method="setCartTemplate"><value>checkout/cart.phtml</value></action>
            <action method="setEmptyTemplate"><value>checkout/cart/noItems.phtml</value></action>
            <action method="chooseTemplate"/>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.top_methods" as="top_methods" translate="label">
                <label>Payment Methods Before Checkout Button</label>
                <block type="checkout/onepage_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage" template="checkout/onepage/link.phtml"/>
            </block>

            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="checkout.cart.form.before" as="form_before" translate="label">
                <label>Shopping Cart Form Before</label>
            </block>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.methods" as="methods" translate="label">
                <label>Payment Methods After Checkout Button</label>
                <block type="checkout/onepage_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage" template="checkout/onepage/link.phtml"/>
                <block type="checkout/multishipping_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.multishipping" template="checkout/multishipping/link.phtml"/>
            </block>

            <block type="checkout/cart_coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon" as="coupon" template="checkout/cart/coupon.phtml"/>
            <block type="checkout/cart_shipping" name="checkout.cart.shipping" as="shipping" template="checkout/cart/shipping.phtml"/>
            <block type="checkout/cart_crosssell" name="checkout.cart.crosssell" as="crosssell" template="checkout/cart/crosssell.phtml"/>

            <block type="checkout/cart_totals" name="checkout.cart.totals" as="totals" template="checkout/cart/totals.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
```

After that you will see shopping cart block on your CMS page. If you don't need any block from them you can remove that blck from the above code.

Answer (score 0):

if you try to call add to cart from cms page then add url like

```
checkout/cart/add?product=$id&qty=$qty
```

Example-

```
<a href="{{store url='checkout/cart/add?product=5&qty=3'}}">
<img src="{{skin url='images/addtocart.jpg'
}}" alt="product5" /></a>
```